# Best way to clear() StorageMap, DoubleStorageMap, and StorageValue

Tags: storagemap

I have seen this answer: [What is the time complexity of StorageMap::clear()?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4396/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-storagemapclear)

But how possible is it that clear() or clear_prefix() doesn't actually clear all of the storage elements when using u32::MAX when attempting to clear everything?

In the society pallet https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/033d4e86cc7eff0066cd376b9375f815761d653c/frame/society/src/migrations.rs#L343

They use clear with no backups.

Am I unclear on how this works? because in the documentation everything says:

> If the resultant maybe_cursor is Some, then another call is required
> to complete the removal operation

- Uses the term "Attempts": https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageMap.html#method.clear
- https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/storage/trait.StorageDoubleMap.html#tymethod.clear_prefix

Is there a way to check before hand, is there a max amount of elements to remove? Or do we simply just use `res.maybe_cursor.is_some()` and if true, attempt to remove again until its false?